# Ptyhon outlook email extraciton only going back 1 year

Tags: python, email, outlook

I am trying to extract all my emails in python and put them into a text folder for processing. The issue is that the emails only seem to go back 1 year.

```py
import win32com.client 
import codecs
import datetime

name = input('Enter your first name: ')
inbox = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6)
corpus = codecs.open(f'{name}_email_corpus.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
messages = inbox.Items
for message in messages:
    subject = message.Subject
    body = message.body
    corpus.write(subject + '\n')
    corpus.write(body + '\n')
```

If you run this and look at the output text file, you will notice that emails only go back one year. Any advice on how to change this so I can get all email history greater than 1 year old?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a common issue with the enumeration of the messages in Outlook COM.
I solved a similar issue in the past iterating in reverse, something on the line of:

```
...

messages = inbox.Items

message_count = messages.Count

#Iterate in reverse
for i in range(message_count, 0, -1):
    message = messages[i]
    message_date = message.SentOn.strftime('%y-%m-%d')
...
```

(Code truncated for brevity)

Try to see if the first message is older than 1 year.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I tried this but still running into the same problem.

Comment: Can you try to sort the items and check the first message's ReceivedTime?  
First you sort:
`sorted = messages.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', False)`
Then you get the first:
`print(sorted[1].ReceivedTime.strftime('%y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Also, as this relies on Outlook, are you sure that your Org doesn't restrict the maximum amount of emails that get synced with the Exchange Server? Usually there is a "retention policy" set up that automatically archives or deletes emails older than X.

Comment: Well I am able to view emails all the way back from several years.

Comment: What is the oldest date that you can see using the method I described 3 comments ago?

Comment: The oldest date is from 1 year ago, October 15th 2020

Comment: That's what I thought. This is the standard behavior of the "cached" mode in Outlook and it's designed like this to keep the data file small. When you manually check the older emails in Outlook you probably click on "load more from Exchange Server" and the emails gets loaded. Try to follow this guide and see if it helps: https://its.gmu.edu/knowledge-base/why-can-i-only-see-12-months-of-emails-in-outlook/

Comment: I Figured out the problem. It was like you said, it has to do with the emails synced with the exchange server. It only stores emails up to 1 year old on the local machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope I still can help you.

I didn't find any solution using python, only in the Outlook.

You go in the **File** tab and click **Account Settings** and then click in **Account Name and Sync Settings** drag the Mail to keep offline slider to **All**.

After this step you need to go to your inbox and click with the right button and click in **Data File Properties**. In the **General** tab search for **advanced** then you go to the **advanced** tab and uncheck **Use Cached Exchange Mode**

Then you restart Outlook and that's it.